# Get data based on multiple dropdown selection and retrieve the results PHP/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Guy i need help to make this work.

Let's say that in my site you can build your sandwich.
For that i have 2 tables.

[image]

and you  will build everything in checkout.php
[image]

How can i make jquery/ajax give me the unit price and give me the total based on quantity and size of my sandwich?
I know that i have to join tables but how it will work with ajax?
I got part of this working, i just need to know how i will display this all with ajax.

Parts working:
Buttons + and - will change `$value` that is the quantity.
Button x removes.
Parts that i dont know how to do:
Select options dropdowns that will work together and give me total and unit price.
How would you do this?

This is an example that i used so you can help me. :)

This is the complex code that i used,in my other post [My complex post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879899/joining-two-tables-and-change-total-cost-based-on-user-dropdown-selection-php)

Obs:I didn't duplicate my question! here i am asking how to make this client-side, and in my complex post is how to make my dropdowns give me the values using the code that is ready.

this is what i made...
this is my cart.php

```
    function cart(){
    global $conn;

    $fabric_options = '';
    $query2 = "SELECT almofadas.A_id, almofadas.tecido, almofadas.id_price, valores_almofadas.id_price, valores_almofadas.icms_7, valores_almofadas.icms_12
    FROM almofadas 
    INNER JOIN valores_almofadas
    ON almofadas.id_price=valores_almofadas.id_price";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $tecido=$rows['tecido'];
      $id_price=$rows['id_price'];
      $price=$rows['icms_7'];
      $fabric_options .= '<option value="'.$id_price.'">'.$tecido.'</option>';

    }

foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
     if($value > 0){
     if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
     $length = strlen($name) -8;
     $item_id = substr($name,8 , $length);

     $query = "SELECT * 
               FROM gallery2 
               WHERE gallery2.id =".escape_string($item_id). "";
               $run_item = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
               while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_item)){ 
                 $vari   = $rows['variante'];
                 $num    = $rows['title'];
                 $id     = $rows['id'];

  // these are my buttons                  
$btn_add ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-success actions plus" data-action="plus" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></button>';

$btn_remove ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning actions less" data-action="remove" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></button>';

$btn_delete ='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default actions" data-action="delete" product_id="'.$id.'" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';

     if($rows['variante'] < 1){
        $vari="";
        }else{
        $vari = "-".$rows['variante'];
        }

  $product = '
   <tr>
   <td style="width:100px; "><img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" style="width:90%;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
   <td>'.$num.''.$vari.'</td>
   <td style="width:15%;">
     <select id="" class=" fabric select form-control selectpicker" required=""  >
    '. $fabric_options . '  
     </select>
    </td>

    <td>
     <select  id="size" class="select form-control selectpicker" required style="width:80%;" onchange="saveChoice()" >
       <option value="50">50x50</option>
       <option value="40">45x45</option>
     </select>
    </td>

    <td class="product'.$id.'">'.$value.'</td> // this is the amount of items for each row
    <td class="'.$id.'">R$:'.$price.'</td>
    <td>$ ' .$value * $price.'</td>
    <td> 
    '.$btn_add.' '.$btn_remove.' '.$btn_delete.'
    </td>
    </tr>';
           echo $product;  

             } 
          } 
       }
    }   
 }
```

This is the script that i'm using to make my amout update on btn click in checkout.php

```
$('.actions').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var action = $(this).attr('data-action'); //gets the button action
  var id = $(this).attr('product_id'); //id of the products
  console.log("triggered action " + action + " for product " + id); //debugging
  $.ajax({
    url: 'cart_functions.php',
    type : 'GET',
    data: {action:action,prod_id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log("ajax call returned the following: " + JSON.stringify(data)); //debugging
      if (data.result == "success") {
        if (action == "plus" || action == "remove")
        {
          console.log("identified product td for " + id + ": " + $(".product" + id).length); //debugging
          $(".product" + id).text(data.val);//update the UI with the new total of each item
         //rest of the script
```

Comment: RiggsFolley made an accurate comment on your other post, and in this question the opposite is apparently applying. SO isn't meant for user's to create tutorials for others but to help solve problems. I'd suggest sharing some problematic code that you've experienced or showing us what you've tried in specific areas. You'll get better feedback than throwing all of your data structures out at once.

Comment: that is my minimal code!

Comment: I just need an explanation how this will work all together

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'm not seeing any code in this question? Your question appears to be asking _"How do I request data from my server through AJAX?"_ If that is the case, the question is too broad. There are many tutorials online that can help you learn how to make AJAX requests with JQuery. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) is a great example from W3Schools that you should work through, then try asking for help when you run into more specific problems.

Comment: I updated with the code that i'm using

Comment: This looks more like a math problem with a sequence logic misunderstanding. You can do all your hamburger orde on the client-side, since you know all prices and only need quantities to calculate the total price. Before you place the order, `Ajax` can only will be usefull if you have to check if there is still enought cheese in the kitchen... I suggest you look for a paiement solution to place the order instead. And on success, you send the complete order to the kitchen with the client's name and adress. But for now, just think about your math problem and getting the clients info.

Comment: i'm getting only one price for all my products, so my table join is not working.

Comment: So this is your starting point. You have to get all your prices associated with the right product in your form's select options... In order to make the calculations on client-side. Ask a specific question about this and show the relevant code where you have a problem. Forget about ajax for now. Trying to to the math on the server-side is not a great idea.

Comment: I made a better question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907987/get-data-based-on-multiple-dropdown-selection-and-calculates-product-value-ajax) using the code that i tried with ajax